# what is the concept used in solving irrational inequalities?

Tags: inequality

for example to solve for x,  $$\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{x-2}<1$$

what are the basic steps I need to remember while solving such questions?

Comment: Some things to keep in mind: $\sqrt{A}$ only makes sense if $A\geq 0$ and the left hand side only makes sense unless $x\not = 2$. It might be useful to split into cases; $x>2$ and $x<2$ and analyze them seperately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain of the equation is defined by the conditions: $\;x\ge \frac12$ and $x\neq 2$.

We can multiply both sides by $(x-2)^2$, which is positive on the domain of validity of the inequation:
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{x-2}<1\iff \sqrt{2x-1}< x-2 $$
Thus we have two cases:

1. $\frac12\le x<2$: the left-hand side (f the original inequation) is negative, hence the inequality is satisfied.
2. $x>2$:  both  sides are positive, so
   \begin{align}
   \sqrt{2x-1}< x-2 &\iff 2x-1 < (x-2)^2\iff x^2-6x+5>0\\&\iff(x-1)(x-5)> 0\iff\begin{cases}x<1\\\enspace\text{or}\\x>5\end{cases}
   \end{align}
   We  retain only the solutions $x>5$

Summing up these results, we obtain the following set of solutions:
$$\bigl[\tfrac12,2\bigr)\cup(5,+\infty)$$.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question and your very clear answer. I just have an additional question regarding case (1). I see your line of reasoning, but say I want to proceed mechanically. Thus, *should I move as follows?* First get $\sqrt{2x-1}>x-2$, since $x-2<0$ and then solve. But then I get as a solution $1 < x < 5$ and if I put it in the system, I get that (1) is satisfied by  $[1/2 , 1)$, which is wrong. *Where is the problem?* I just don't see it. Thanks  a lot for any feedback! :)

Comment: @Kolmin: The problem is in squaring. To compare two numbers, you can do it by squaring only if both numbers have the same sign, which isn't the case. Just take an example: we have $1 >-2$ *and* $1^2<(-2)^2=4$. We also have $1>-1/2$ *and* $ 1^2>(-1/2)^2=1/4$.

Comment: Oh Right. Thanks a lot! But then, in a sense, there is no way to get a *mechanical* solution for this problem. You *must see* that in (1) the LHS is negative hence smaller than $1$. Or there is such a mechanical procedure?

Comment: If by mechanical procedure, you mean going from the inequation to the solution without having to make any test, I don't think so. But remember a test is a perfectly legitimate part of an algorithm.

Comment: Actually, what I mean is something that can be performed *without thinking*. That is, if we solve an equation of the form $ax^2 + bx = 0$, there is a sense in which we do not have to think. This applies to a lot of inequalities as well. But here it seems that you have to actually see what is going on. If I don't think (and I am rather good at that... ;D ), even if I proceed as in your edit, case (1) ends up "behaving" as follows: I have the two basic requirements $x \geq 1/2$ and $x <2$ and then I solve and get  $x<1$ and $x>5$, which doesn't work. *[Of course, correct me where I am wrong]*

Comment: I wasn't clear enough (or the layout…): the solutions $x<1$ or $x>5$ are only for case 2. For case 1, after the sign test, there's nothing to do since the inequation is *ipso facto* satisfied.

Comment: No no, it was not the layout (but I do appreciate your vote of confidence... :) ). I see what you mean. I am not sure I did actually explain myself. But anyway, thanks a lot for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}-(x-2)}{x-2},$$
$x\ge\frac12$ and $x\not=2$

$$f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2x-1}-(x-2)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=5$$

[image]

Then $f(x)<0$ if $\frac12 \le x<2$ or $x>5$

Answer: $\frac12 \le x<2$ or $x>5$

Comment: I didn't understand what you did :(

Comment: @danny: I edited